# white-space: pre-wrap not working in IE

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I am using `white-space: pre-wrap`. Content is not being wrapped in IE in Quirk mode.

Is there any solution to get it working for quirk mode?

**Note:** It is working fine in strict mode of IE8 and IE9.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quirks mode is for backwards compatibility with very old browsers like IE5, which do not comply with standards (aka strict) mode.  The `pre-wrap` property is supported in IE8 and higher, but not IE 5-7:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html

In this situation, there are two options:

- Don't support browsers that are non-compliant with w3 standards
- Send incompatible IE versions a different stylesheet using [IE conditionals](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)