# Why do we this line of code in normalize.css?

Tags: css, properties, cross-browser, whitespace

The code below

```
// Improve readability of pre-formatted text in all browsers.
    pre {
      white-space: pre;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

is taken from https://github.com/yuanyan/pre/blob/master/src/normalize.less

Could anybody please tell me why do we need this

```
  white-space: pre;
```

as the second line overrides it.
I know it is needed, but who can tell me why? Is that because of the browser support? Probably not the way it is used here. What's the sense to override values?

P.S. The pre-wrap property is supported in IE8 and higher, but not IE 5-7 -that's what [Alex W says here @ SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785247/white-space-pre-wrap-not-working-in-ie)

Comment: the second line overrides the first one only if browser understands this rule. First line is used as a fallback.

Comment: Is that a fallback for IE7 and lower?

Comment: Yes and any older browser version that doesn't support pre-wrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pre-wrap` wasn't supported by all browsers. These days every browser support it. So it's just a fallback for old browsers.